# How to use service layer in node js

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am new for Node js. I have use express and sequelize for my application.

This is my router function.

```
router.post('/add-merchant', [
    check('name').not().isEmpty(),
    check('city').not().isEmpty(),
    check('state').not().isEmpty(),
    check('country').not().isEmpty(),
], (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const errors = validationResult(req);

        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.json({ errors: errors.array()});
        }

        var merchant = merchantService.addMerchant(req);
        return res.json(merchant)
    } catch (error) {
        return res.json({"status": "error", "message": error.message})
    }
});
```

I have created file called merchantService.js

I have added code for inserting data in merchantService.js and tried like this

```
var merchant = merchantService.addMerchant(req);
```

But I cannot get any data from merchant service. Here is my merchant service code

var models = require("../models");

```
var merchantService = {
    addMerchant: (req) => {
        models.merchants.create(req.body).then((merchant) => {
            return merchant.dataValues
        });
    }
}

module.exports = merchantService;
```

I cannot find the issue. Please help anyone to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To put it simply the `merchantService.addMerchant` function is __asynchronous call__ to DB which means you __can't use return statement__ to return data. You need to use either callbacks or promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are managing an async task in a sync way and it doesn't work.

You should change your request handler in this way:

```
router.post('/add-merchant', [
  check('name').not().isEmpty(),
  check('city').not().isEmpty(),
  check('state').not().isEmpty(),
  check('country').not().isEmpty(),
], (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

     merchantService.addMerchant(req).then((merchant)=>{
      res.json(merchant)
    })
  } catch (error) {
    return res.json({ "status": "error", "message": error.message })
  }
});
```

And fix your merchant service like this (see the `return` value in order to start the promise chain):

```
const merchantService = {
  addMerchant: (req) => {
    return models.merchants.create(req.body)
      .then((merchant) => {
        return merchant.dataValues
      });
  }
}

module.exports = merchantService;
```

Comment: One note: services in general shouldn’t know about req,res or any api specific concepts. It is better to pass req.body to service directly. That way service is reusable across system